# Vue's reactivity changes data type

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue.js 2 component where one of the data members should be an array of a custom class (Vector) that extends from Array. However, when I assign the array to the data member, the array's items are no longer Vectors, but plain Array's.

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/nervous-tu-7en2q?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Main parts:

vector.js

```html
export default class Vector extends Array {
  /** Creat a vector from all arguments. */
  constructor(...args) { ... }

  get x() {
    return this[0];
  }
  get y() {
    return this[1];
  }
};

export const square = [
  new Vector(0, 0),
  new Vector(1, 1),
]
```

Component:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{ title }}
    ({{ square[0][0] }}, {{ square[0][1] }})
    ({{ square[1].x }}, {{ square[1].y }})
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { square } from './vector.js';

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      square,
      title: 'hello'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.square)
  }
};
</script>
```

If you look at the console output, you will see the square is now an array of two arrays in stead of an array of two Vectors:

(2) [Array(2), Array(2)]

Questions:

1. is this supposed to happen and if yes, why?
2. can it be prevented? One option would be to prevent it from being reactive by moving it out of the data part, but that kills the good reactivity part of course.

Comment: This is one of the main issues related to vue2. However, this should be solved with vue3 or the composition api. The reactivity mechanism works different in the latter, based on proxies. Which should preserve the constructor of your vector instead of destructing it. See: https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what's the issue but I tried rewriting almost the same using a different pattern, could you check if this solves your problem? If not hopefully a different approach would get you more clues.

Basically for what I see you will get a `2 numbers array` everytime you create a `vector`, are you expecting it to be of other type?

#### Here is my rewrite:

*vector.js*

```js
const vector = (x, y) => ({
    values: [x, y],
    setX(newValue) {
      this.values[0] = newValue
      return this
    },
    setY(newValue) {
      this.values[1] = newValue
      return this
    },
    getX() {
      return this.values[0]
    },
    getY() {
      return this.values[1]
    }
})

export default vector

export const square = [vector(0, 0).values, vector(1,1).values];
```

```js
<script>
import vector, { square } from "./vector.js";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      square,
      vector: vector(1, 2).values,
      title: "Corners",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('square', this.square);
    console.log('vector', this.vector);
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for this late reply. You are now doing the conversion to array yourself by passing .values into the square and this.vector. So you still cannot use it as a vector as in this.square[0].getX().
I guess @RonaldT 's comment makes clear you cannot prevent this 'upcast'.